# Show that there is an open interval $I$ centered at $a$ for which $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$

Tags: calculus

> Assume $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists and is positive. Use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to show that there is an open interval $I$ centered at $a$ for which $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$.

We are given that $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \quad 0 < |x-a| < \delta \quad \implies \quad |f(x)-L| < \epsilon.$$ where $L$ is positive.

How do I use this to show we have an open interval $I$ where $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Expand $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ by getting rid of the absolute values and cleverly choose $\epsilon$ in terms of your positive $L$.

Comment: We have $L-\epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$. How do I choose $\epsilon$?

Comment: Remember $\epsilon$ can be ANY positive number. You need $f(x)$ to be bigger than SOME positive number. You've already gotten $f(x)>L-\epsilon$. Now pick me a good epsilon.

Comment: Say $\epsilon = L - 1$.

Comment: @Puzzled417 That might not be a positive number anymore. Say your $L=0.00002$, then $L-1$ is kinda bad..

Comment: I can say $\epsilon = L$.

Comment: Now you're talking. :) That works perfectly. Although if you're squeamish like me, you can choose $\epsilon =L/2$ to get a better lower bound of $L-L/2=L/2$ rather than just $0$, but this is just personal preference.